# Beamer outside notes word wrap problem

Tags: beamer, notes

I am adding some notes to my slides. My notes are very long (about 3 lines in the slide), and when I use `\note[enumerate]{\item ... }` stuff, (it is note outside frame) the text in the note slide does not get appropriately wrapped and some of the last characters of each line are cut.

If I just use `\note{}` without enumerate or itemize, then the left and right margin look right.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. While making the example, I found that actually my custom theme was causing this problem, as with default theme it looked alright.

Comment: Now the problem is I have no idea how to fix this style file. :)

Comment: Try to bring it down to the part that makes problems and then ask here (possibly in a new question to avoid confusion).

Comment: I've closed 'too localised' as this is about a style file, which we don't have. Feel free to post a  new question or to reopen this one with more detail.